# What does this arrow mean in UML class diagram?

Tags: uml, class-diagram

[image]

What strikes me in this arrow is that it starts in **bold**. How is it different compared to normal arrow? What relationship it indicates?

*I found it in Head First Design Pattern book. Page 159*

Comment: I have a (probably older) version of this book were on p. 161 this connector is hand-drawn. Jim's answer is the right one. Also the arrow below is not exactly a triangle but some "artistic" element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such "bold end" in UML. It must be a glitch from the author's drawing tool.

Comment: I would say the book in general seems poor based on this single picture. Not only the "bold" arrow end is a glitch but the other end is also non-compliant with UML specification. The arrow should either have a dashed line and an empty triangle head if the Dough interface is provided by NYPizzaStore or a dashed line and an open arrow head if it is a required one. Solid line with full triangle is used in interaction diagrams for synchronous message and in profile diagrams only. This head is neither a full triangle nor an open arrow, rather something in between which is totally wrong.

Comment: Agreed. Most people use pidgin UML, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

`Arrows` denote connections in `UML`, Please see the picture below.

[image: arrows in UML]

Please read the complete guide [here][2]

Comment: The link is broken.